# Jquery DataTable load data slowly when applied responsive property to true

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am newbie in using Jquery DataTable and I am having around 700 records coming from the backend. On the UI I am using datatable to render those records and having following properties to it.

```
var datatable = $('#table').DataTable({
                select: true,
                searching: true,
                paging: true,
                deferRender: true,
                pageLength: 10,
                autoWidth: true,
                orderCellsTop: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                fixedHeader: {
                    header: true,
                    footer: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                fixedColumns: {
                    leftColumns: 3
                },
});
```

Whenever I apply `responsive: true` it takes 1 minute to load 700 records and when I remove `responsive: true` it loads 700 records in 2 seconds. I really don't know how to handle this issue as I need my table to be responsive.

Thank you in advance.